# Try/Catch on StreamReader(string Path) used as base class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a Class that Inherits .net StreamReader. And inside that class, its constructor inherits the base method StreamReader(string path)...

```
public class CsvFileReader : StreamReader
{
    public CsvFileReader(string filename) : base (stream)
    {
       ..do whatever
    }
}
```

this block of code is being called as follows..

```
using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader(filename))
{
  ...Do whatever somemore...
}
```

My question is.. How do you catch an exception on the reader?  You cannot catch it from the CsvFileReader instance (i.e. wrap the using statement) and of course not in the dll...

please assist..

For Clarity

I tried the following implementation and it fails on the constructor call, not on the using block...

```
try 
  {
      using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader(filename))
      {
        ...Do whatever Again...
      }
  } catch(Exception e)
    {
       Do whatever with the Exception..
    }
```

Comment: I'm not really sure I get what you're asking. Why can't you wrap the `using` statement with a try/catch?

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot - Thanks for your reply..  When I try, the exception is thrown at the inherited method.. Not at the reader instance.. If that makes sense..

Comment: Remember that `using` is a coding sugar for `try-finally`. If you may want to use a `try-catch-finally` block in that case. What exception are you getting and in what line?

Comment: @Andrew - Thanks for your reply.. I'm forcing an exception in a case where the user has the document already open upon execution.. "The process cannot access the file..........because it is being used by another process.   It is being thrown at the constructor..  Thanks again..

Comment: Also I am in debug mode but my in my Exceptions setting I have System.IO.IO Exceptions turned off..

Comment: And what's the issue then? You can't catch your own exception?

Comment: @Andrew - Yes I can't catch my own exception..   I turned off the System.IO Exception in debug mode so I could handle it.. But its still thrown by VS.

Comment: I don't think you should turn that off. Can you post how you are trying to catch it?

Comment: try {
             using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader(filename))
            {

Comment: Remove using statement if you want to catch the exception and directly instantiate it within try block.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want the CsvFileReader constructor to do something when the base class throws. E.g. wrap the exception or try and recover from it.

Unfortunately if `StreamReader` fails in the constructor you won't get an instance of `CsvFileReader` so any code you write in `CsvFileReader` can't do anything meaningful.

It would be nice if `StreamReader` provided a constructor that took zero arguments and use that one instead but since `StreamReader` doesn't there's nothing further you can do. You're really only left with the following options.

- Don't implement that constructor. Force the user to pass in a stream instead That way they won't get to your constructor unless they have a valid stream.
- Accept that the base constructor will throw and let the user deal with it as you did. Adding try{} catch{} around the using or use `try{} catch{} finally {dispose}`
- Inherit from `TextReader` and implement the features that you need and provide a constructor that takes in a string that suits your purposes